# The use of "sia" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood, conjunctions

I have always understood "sia" to be a subjunctive form of the verb "essere". Hence, I don't understand its usage in the following sentence:

> Questo modo di viaggiare non è  ancora abbastanza diffuso, sia perché costa troppo, e sia perché a molti manca il coraggio.

Could someone explain this?

Comment: In addition to what is said by @abarisone, in English it would be "**both** because it costs too much **and** because...".

Comment: I revised the sentence since there were a couple of mistakes, and added @Charo's comment to my answer.

Comment: @abarisone I agree that the usage of "mancare" was strange, but I took the sentence directly from a textbook - not to say it need be correct.

Comment: @David: I think this could be another question. Would you like to ask it?

Comment: @Charo Wouldn't it actually be "'both' because it costs too much and 'also' because...". In other words, the "sia"s are the words "both" and "also", as opposed to "both" and "and".

Comment: @David: I really don't undrestand very well the difference between "both ... and ..." and "both ... and also ...", but [Collins dictionary](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/sia) translates "sia... sia..." as "both ... and ...".

Comment: @David The original sentence, to be correct, could also have been written as "_e sia perché molti mancano **di** coraggio_"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find an explanation about this use of [sia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sia/) in Treccani's dictionary:

> **sia**. – Terza persona sing. del congiuntivo pres. del verbo essere, usata come congiunzione disgiuntiva correlativa: *è una casa
>   confortevole, sia d’inverno sia d’estate; sia lui, sia un altro, per
>   me è lo stesso* (il secondo elemento della correlazione può essere
>   introdotto anche da o oppure da *che: sia lui o un altro, sia d’inverno
>   che d’estate*). Sia è usato inoltre come formula di consenso o di
>   rassegnazione e come modo di concedere: *sia!, così sia!, sia pure!* (v.
>   essere1, n. 6).

So *sia* is used here as disjunctive conjunction that establishes a correlation  between two elements.

On this [Zanichelli blog post](https://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2010/09/16/le-congiunzioni-1/) about coordinative conjunctions, you can find more information:

> Secondo il loro significato le congiunzioni coordinative si possono
>   suddividere in:
>
> • **copulative**: possono essere positive ( **e**, **anche**, **pure**) o negative (
>   **né**, **neppure**, **nemmeno**) e collegano due elementi con il semplice
>   accostamento: ho comprato la frutta **e** il latte; non mi piace giocare a
>   calcio, **né** giocare a tennis.
>
> • **disgiuntive**: **o**, **oppure**, **altrimenti** ecc. Collegano due parole
>   ponendole in alternativa: preferisci andare al cinema **o** a teatro?;
>   accendi la luce, **altrimenti** non riesco a leggere. La congiunzione **o**,
>   oltre al valore disgiuntivo, può avere anche valore esplicativo: la
>   semiologia, **o** scienza dei segni, si è sviluppata molto in questo
>   secolo.
>
> • **avversative**: **ma**, **però**, **tuttavia**, **anzi**, **piuttosto**, eppure ecc.
>   Collegano due parole, o frasi,che si contrappongono l’una all’altra:
>   oggi c’è il sole, **ma** non fa tanto caldo; questo vestito è molto bello,
>   **però** è troppo costoso; Luca non è antipatico, **anzi** è molto spiritoso;
>   l’esame non è andato bene, **eppure** avevo studiato molto; sono molto
>   stanca, **tuttavia** verrò al cinema con te; non ho voglia di cucinare,
>   **piuttosto** andiamo al ristorante;
>
> • **dichiarative** o **esplicative**: **cioè**, **infatti**, **ossia**, **vale a dire**, ecc.
>   Introducono una parola o una frase che spiega o precisa ciò che è
>   detto dalla parola o frase precedente: mio fratello è un veterinario,
>   cioè cura gli animali; non sono abituata a bere il vino, **infatti** mi è
>   venuto il mal di testa; ho una forte congiuntivite, ossia
>   un’infiammazione agli occhi; Marta è stata bocciata, **vale a dire** che
>   dovrà ripetere l’anno.
>
> • **conclusive**: **dunque**, **quindi**, **ebbene**, **perciò**, **pertanto**, **allora**, ecc.
>   Segnalano che il secondo elemento è la conseguenza del primo: Marco è
>   ingrassato molto, **dunque** deve mettersi a dieta; oggi è molto freddo,
>   **quindi** copriti bene; ho lavorato tutto il giorno, **perciò** sono molto
>   stanca; non ci siamo comportati bene, **pertanto** dobbiamo chiede scusa;
>   Anna non ha voglia di uscire, **allora** rimane a casa.
>
> *• **correlative**: **e…e**, **o…o**, **né…né**, **sia…sia**, **non solo…ma anche**, ecc.
>   Stabiliscono una relazione tra due o più elementi: stasera o vengo con
>   te a teatro o vado con Marta al cinema; Silvia non è né grassa né
>   magra; ascolto **sia** la musica leggera **sia** la musica classica; è un
>   libro non  solo interessante, ma anche molto divertente.*

The equivalent in English would be:

> ... **both** because it costs too much **and** because ...